# EF Migrations: Move Table from 2 Column PK to Single Column causes ALTER before DROP and fails

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 4.3.1 Code First Migrations. I have a table like:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=0)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Store { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}​
```

I have an existing table created with the above code. I then moved it to a single-column Primary Key:

```
public class Product
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Store { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}​
```

This causes EF to fail in the next automatic migration, complaining:

> ALTER TABLE [Product] ALTER COLUMN [Store] nvarchar
>
> The object 'PK_Product' is dependent on column 'Store'. ALTER
>   TABLE ALTER COLUMN Store failed because one or more objects access this
>   column.

Clearly the PK_Product needs to be dropped before attempting to fire this ALTER statement (why is it altering the column at all?), but instead the migration fails.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Workarounds?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with an automatic migration. You'll have to create a migration using `Add-Migration` and then change it so it only modifies the PK.

The migration can be as simple as:

```
public partial class TheMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("Products", new[] { "Store", "Sku" });
        AddPrimaryKey("Products", "Sku");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("Products", new[] { "Sku" });
        AddPrimaryKey("Products", new[] { "Store", "Sku" });
    }
}
```

EF is altering the column because, when it's part of a `Key`, it's implicitly `NOT NULL`. 
You can leave it as-is, add a `[Required]` attribute, or allow EF to alter the column **after** dropping the PK.

Comment: Add-Migration pregenerated the above commands (and more). It turns out they were simply out of order - by moving DropPrimaryKey as you have above here before the column change, it was resolved. So to be clear the final migration went DropPrimaryKey, AlterColumn, AddPrimaryKey. I do think this is a bug in Migrations given the simplicity of the solution, rather than an inherent limitation.

Comment: Yup, hence my **bold** in the "after" :-)